# Loading Colored Lines into Browser with threejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, three.js, data-visualization

I'm trying to draw colored lines in my browser -- there are no meshes involved. I currently query a MySQL database where geometry and other attributes are stored, and translate these objects into text blocks that each produce a single line object to be read by `threejs`.

```
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
color: 0xF2AA20,
linewidth: 5});
var line = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(1040,-406,-760));
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(1040,-406,-709));
scene.add(line);
```

This ultimately produces a stand-alone html document with data hard-coded: http://thomasshouler.com/datavis/wrapper/axial.html

I need to make this more scalable. We're currently loading ~1,300  of the 170 million records that will ultimately need to be visualized. An initial logical step would seemingly be to store the objects and attributes in separate files (JSON?) that could then be loaded into an html template (certainly cleaner, I expect efficient?).

I assume this would be pretty simple for most, but examples I find are typically far more complex and therefore difficult for me to incorporate into my work. Could somebody please provide an example which loads a single line via JSON format into the browser?

Comment: How to load `JSON` depends on whether you want to use a library like `jQuery` or native browser features only. Using `jQuery` certainly makes it easier.

Comment: Try merging your geometry for better performance. Each mesh means an extra draw call for the GPU. If you want to apply different colors to lines, you might use vertex colors if you decide to merge the geometry.

Answer (score 0):

If it's going to be displayed statically (ie no frame by frame updates) then simply drawing on a canvas is probably the best approach as redrawing a few thousand lines might be fine for a GPU, but millions is definitely pushing it (1). `linewidth` is also not supported everywhere in WebGL but works fine with the canvas methods. Once drawn on a canvas there is no frame by frame redrawing required, and you can bypass three.js entirely if you don't need the 3D. And yes, you should export the data you need from the database as JSON, then process that in a loop rather than building a HTML page with all the instructions.

(1) You wouldn't be able to fill an image with millions of lines and not display a terrible mess in the process, so you'll have to filter the data in some way.

Edit: Also have a look at [Circos](http://circos.ca/), which might just be what you need.

Comment: Linewidth is not available in Windows (an angle limitation).